# How can I sort my inventory based on variable?

Tags: cassandra, ansible

I have ansible inventory file as follows:

```
[dc1]
dc1-node0 ansible_host=10.1.0.1 seed=no
dc1-node1 ansible_host=10.1.0.2 seed=yes 
dc1-node2 ansible_host=10.1.0.2 seed=yes 
[dc2]
dc2-node ansible_host=10.2.0.1 seed=yes
dc2-node1 ansible_host=10.2.0.2 seed=no
dc2-node2 ansible_host=10.2.0.2 seed=yes
```

I need to write a playbook which will start the seed node at first and then other nodes.
Again, user can provide only one node as well. So my playbook should be able to check if it is seed or non-seed and do accordingly.

So far, I am able to write playbook as follows:

```
- hosts:  "{{ dbhosts }}"
  serial: 1
  vars:
  vars_prompt:
  - name: "dbhosts"
    prompt: "Which hosts would you like to run?"
    private: no
  gather_facts: no
  tasks:
  - name: is dse already running?
    shell: service dse status | grep dead | wc -l
    register: svc_dse_dead
    ignore_errors: true
  - debug:
       msg: "Is DSE service dead (0 = No; 1 = Yes)? Current status =  {{svc_dse_dead.stdout}}"
  - name: Start dse service
    service:
      name: dse
      state: started
    become: true
    become_method: sudo
    when:
         - svc_dse_dead.stdout == "1"        
  - name: Pausing execution to stablize gossipping between nodes
    pause:
      minutes: 2
    when:  
      svc_dse_dead.stdout == 1
```

But this playbook is not sorting hosts based on seed nodes.
Is there any way I can achieve that? 
Please advise some ideas.

Thanks

Comment: You cannot re-sort the inventory list. Your English description is unclear and your code doesn't make understanding any easier. You should likely rethink your objectives.

Answer (score 0):

For example, you can generate dynamic groups:

```
---
- hosts: all
  gather_facts: no
  tasks:
    - group_by:
        key: "seed_{{ 'yes' if seed | default(false,boolean=true) | bool else 'no' }}"

- hosts: seed_yes:seed_no
  gather_facts: no
  serial: 1
  tasks:
    - debug: msg="{{ seed | default('unknown') }}"
```

`serial: 1` is crucial here, as `seed_yes:seed_no` pattern will ensure `yes`-hosts are at first place, so we should iterate them one by one.

If speed is required you can avoid `serial`, but will have to create two identical plays – one for `yes` and one for `no`:

```
---
- hosts: all
  gather_facts: no
  tasks:
    - group_by:
        key: "seed_{{ 'yes' if seed | default(false,boolean=true) | bool else 'no' }}"

- hosts: seed_yes
  gather_facts: no
  tasks:
    - debug: msg="{{ seed | default('unknown') }}"

- hosts: seed_no
  gather_facts: no
  tasks:
    - debug: msg="{{ seed | default('unknown') }}"
```

Comment: Wow! That's awesome. Thanks.
Where can I get more documentation on this if statement in groupby? I haven't find it yet.
Thanks.